# Graph API missing type property?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Request: https://graph.facebook.com/1598234077

Response:

```
{
   "id": "1598234077",
   "name": "Steve Taylor",
   "first_name": "Steve",
   "last_name": "Taylor",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/people/Steve-Taylor/1598234077",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_GB"
}
```

According to the documentation, there's supposed to be a `type` property in there, but this isn't happening, at not least at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Use Request https://graph.facebook.com/1598234077**?metadata=1** you will get "type". Otherwise you don't.

But if you call in the graph explorer it will return type. If you call using API in your application, it wont. You need to include metadata.

its called "introspection" by adding metadata argument to your request. I had a tough time to find this. Facebook documentation doesn't help much.

GET http://graph.facebook.com/object_id?metadata=1